# get_current_user doesn't work (OAuth2PasswordBearer problems)

Tags: python, fastapi

This is actually the first time it doesn't work, I mean I've practiced this before, but now I have no idea what's wrong.

So I am trying to implement basic function [`get_current_user`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/get-current-user/) for FastAPI, but somehow it doesn't work.

When I try in swagger  Authorization works fine, but endpoint with current user simply doesn't work.

So this is part that belongs to endpoint file:

```
router = APIRouter(prefix='/api/v1/users')
router1 = APIRouter()

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='/api-token-auth/')


@router1.post('/api-token-auth/')
async def auth(form: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = await utils.get_user_by_username(form.username, db)  # type: User
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    if not utils.validate_password(form.password, user.hashed_password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    return await utils.create_token(user.id, db)


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print(token)
    user = await utils.get_user_by_token(token, db)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )

    return user


@router.get("/me", response_model=DisplayUser)
async def read_users_me(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return current_user
```

and this is function that creates token (I have checked and it is 1000% works and returns string):

```
async def create_token(user_id: int, db: Session):
    """Token generation"""
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    token = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(25))
    created_token = Token(
        expires=datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=2),
        user_id=user_id,
        token=token
    )
    db.add(created_token)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(created_token)
    token = AuthUser.from_orm(created_token)
    return token.token
```

But when I `print(token)` in `get_current_user` function it prints `undefined`. And I dunno why. Am I using dependency wrong or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it prints undefined it seems like the frontend is expecting the response in a different format (since `undefined` is what using an undefined object key in Javascript as a key will result in). Have you tried formatting the token retrieval response as expected from an oauth2 response? https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/ - if the client sends in `undefined` as its token, there isn't much you can do server side in the `get_current_user` function.

Comment: @MatsLindh Well this is embarassing, but i had NO idea that field has to be named access_token.  THANK YOU SO MUCH KIND SIR!!!! Now it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it prints undefined it seems like the frontend is expecting the response in a different format (since undefined is what using an undefined object key in Javascript as a key will result in).

The OAuth2 response [should have the token under `access_token` by default](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/):

> access_token (required) The access token string as issued by the authorization server.
>
> token_type (required) The type of token this is, typically just the string “bearer”.

Example response from the above link:

```
{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "create_token(user.id, db)" ensure the returned token contains these two values.
{
"access_token":"",
"token_type":"bearer"
}